# New to MYSQL/PHP and need help rendering a MYSQL array output in to a PHP numbered list

Tags: php, html

Code posted below. I currently get the correct results as the code would call for below.

**- Fred Jones. Walked to the store.**

**- Nancy Schmitt. Went to the airport.** 

**- Tom Smith. Mowed the yard.**

What i'm trying to do is get output like so. Sometimes there are multiple tasks. A list is generated every day so the number of tasks and customers may change.

**1) Fred Jones. Walked to the store.**
**2) Nancy Schmitt. Went to the airport.** 

**3) Tom Smith. Mowed the yard.**

Is there any way to generate a "numbered list" of my output?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE taskDate = curdate()";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $html .= " \n ". "- " . $row["customer"]. ". " . $row["task"]. " \n "; 
            }
   
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "<p class='lead'><em>No records were found.</em></p>";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Do you want the output to be rendered in a numbered list output? If so, please edit the question to have the first tag in php since its more related to php than any mysqli statements. And can you please explain what the use of `$html` ?

Comment: $html is the variable I use for the body of a email message sent using php pear mailer.

Comment: You can add a $i = 1 before while statement , and add it to $html concat statement and after that line do $i++

Comment: If it helps; i input customers and tasks daily into a DB. At the end of the day I have to send a report detailing the customer and task I worked on every day. Right now everything is done on paper. The code I posted queries the days tasks and sends an email. Right now the body of the email looks like the first list I posted above. I was wanting a numbered list in the email output instead

Comment: I tried Rahulvramesh's suggestion and it works great. but for some reaso I cant get the new line to work. I have to missing something small.

`code` $i = 1;
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                    $html .= $i++ . ") " . $row["customer"]. ". " . $row["task"]. "." . "\n";  `code`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that ended up working for me. Thanks for the help community.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE taskDate = curdate()";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $i = 1;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $html .= $i++ . ") " . $row["customer"]. ". " . $row["task"]. "." . "<br>"; 

            }
   
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "<p class='lead'><em>No records were found.</em></p>";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
```